# Do we need [tag:scientific-development]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

We have [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) and [technological-development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technological-development). The later being used to ask question about how technology develops *within* your fictive world.

This seems to exclude scientific research that doesn't directly pertain to technology. If I for instance am interested in the scientific worldview a pre flight society on the moon of a gas giant might have, tagging as [technological-development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technological-development) would not be appropriate, but neither would [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based).

I propose we introduce a tag [scientific-development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-development) for questions like these, we might rename [technological-development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technological-development), add it as a synonym or make it a separate tag altogether.

What are your thoughts on this?

As an example of a question that could use this tag, I present you with [What if time travel had to take into account spatial distance?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1464/328) Which in part asks, what kind of experiments scientists might perform to study time travel with certain restraints. This doesn't quite fit under the [technological-development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technological-development) umbrella, but would certainly benefit from a tag that indicates a focus on in-universe scientists.

Answer (score 3):

As is usual with questions about tags. If you have a **genuine use** (as in, you were writing / saw a question and went *"That needs [scientific-development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-development)!"*) just go ahead and make the tag. As long as you **make sure you write the tag wiki for it.**

Review it in a month or so and see if the tag has anyone else using it. If not, considered deleting it from the question, which will automatically kill the tag.

I would much prefer seeing questions about merging tags than I would see questions about making them on meta. If you think the tag is needed for a current question, use it. Chances are someone else will probably want to use it as well. If its too similar to another, someone will see and propose a synonym/merge.